# How is this helper $.each() function assigning values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Will somebody please explain how part of this function operates?

```
var result = {}

$.each(this.serializeArray(), function(i, v) {
    result[v.name] = v.value;
});
```

From the above code, I do not understand the following:

`result[v.name] = v.value;`

I don't understand how this is giving me the results I am getting, which is an object with name value pairs. How is this working?

Comment: This is assigning a value to a property of an object. What is there not to understand? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "why this code is working as it is"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// result is defined as empty object
var result = {}


// your each binding most likely is inside a $('form').submit(function(){ in here });
// so this.searializeArray() converts ( whatever "this" is in your scope )  an JavaScript array of objects you iterate over where function(i <- is the key, v <- is the object)

$.each(this.serializeArray(), function(i, v) {
    // so for every object in your array you take the value and assign a new object in your initial empty result object with object.name as key and object.value as value 
    result[v.name] = v.value;
});

// so result may look like this after that

result ==   { 
"fooname":"foovalue",
"barname":1337
}
```